# Inverse prediction of percentile

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, prediction-interval, inverse-prediction

Suppose we consider a linear normal regression
$y\sim$Normal($\mu,\sigma$) and $\mu=a+bx$. I have seen documentations for methods for obtaining a confidence interval for $x$ for a specific mean value of $y$. Suppose instead of the mean $y$, I want a confidence interval in $x$ for top 5%ile of $y$ (e.g., so that prediction in $x$ will be lower than that for the mean $y$, provided $b>0$).

I found a method for getting a confidence interval of percentile in $y$ (https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/317). But I don't know what a next step is.

Ideally, I want a method that works for any other distributions (e.g., gamma distribution and log-normal distribution).

Comment: Do you mean quantile regression?